# Jscript working for me, but not other user

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, jscript

We have a third party app that fires some events onkeypress of a textbox. We don't want these events, and so I added the following just before the closing body tag - to remove the onkeypress event.

I am scratching my head because it works perfectly when I open the webpage on my desktop.  But when the other user opens the page, the onkeypress event is still triggered.  I don't understand why and how to stop it?

I added an alert to see if the script is actually triggered on their side, and they DO get the alert.  So - I am puzzled.  Any suggestions?

```
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).on('load', function () {

        document.getElementById("TheControl_ToTextBox").removeAttribute("onkeypress");
        document.getElementById("TheControl_CcTextBox").removeAttribute("onkeypress");

        alert("Test Page Load: Ingore This Message");

    });

</script>


</body>

</html>
```

EDIT ________________________________

I am adding the html code that is generated for one of the text boxes for reference

```
<span class="ComposeHeaderValue">
                <input name="TheControl$ToTextBox" type="text" readonly="readonly" id="TheControl_ToTextBox" tabindex="1" onkeypress="return TheControl.RY(this, event);" />
            </span>
```

Edit ________________________________________

Additionally, I added an alert to spit out the element ID of the two textboxes.  That works successfully for everyone.  So, in the least, I do know the element ID's are correct.

I also downloaded and installed the latest version of jquery and referenced the local version.  Still works when launching browser on my desktop . . and still does not work when launching browser from any other desktop pc.

```
 <script src="Utils/jquery-3.4.0.js"></script>
```

I am totally out of ideas . . .

Comment: The logic will only remove event listeners attached with the inline binding.  Not those added with jQuery or with the `addEventListener` method

Comment: @taplar - Understood.  Any chance you can help me understand why it actually works for me? When I launch the page from the server (not local) it works perfectly.  The onkeypress is removed.  When someone else loads same page from same server (not local) . . . it fails.  I guess the puzzling piece for me is . . Why does it work when I load the page from server, on my desktop?

Comment: What do you mean by "on my desktop"?  Both of you are using a browser, no?  I guess I'm confused by the need for that detail.

Comment: @taplar - correct, we are both using a browser.  We are both using IE 11.09.  When I launch the page (on IE browser) from my desktop, the onkeypress events have been removed, as desired.  When my coworker launches the same page (on IE browser) from their desktop . .  the onkeypress events do still trigger, which we do not want to happen.  However, the Alert message does pop up.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the elements on the box that it does not work on?  There may be some sort of a timing issue going on.  Are these elements created dynamically?

Comment: @Taplar - I have added the html for one of the textboxes that is not working.  I don't see anything that stands out to me.  Understanding that jquery is not something I am proficient at . . . making it more of a struggle to understand why it works for me, but not my coworker.    In short, we want these two text boxes to be locked/read only.  However, when simply setting the html attribute to readonly=true, it fails because the onkeypress event is triggered and overrides it.

Comment: Is there a difference between how you are serving the files? Are they coming from the file system, or from an HTTP server?

Comment: @ZevSpitz - everyone (including me) is accessing the files via the same http url/server.  I am making live changes on the server, and then using the same url that everyone else uses, for my testing.